# Using lower_bound function in loop is giving runtime error?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, binary-search, lower-bound

The following code is causing runtime error.In the given code 'blocked' and 'passed' are two string vectors and have lengths bl and pl respectively. 'low' is an iterator of a string vector.

```
int pos;
vector<string> f;
vector<string>::iterator low;
for(int i=0;i<bl;i++) {
        string x=blocked[i];
        low=lower_bound(passed.begin(),passed.end(),x); //lower_bound function is used on the vector 'passed'.
        index=low-passed.begin(); //finding the index of the string in the vector 'passed'.
        string y=passed[index];
        int xlen=x.length();
        int ylen=y.length();
        int minlen=min(xlen,ylen);
        for(int i=0;i<minlen;i++) {
            if(x[i]!=y[i]) {
                pos=i;
                break;
              }
            }
            string h=x.substr(0,pos+1);
            f.push_back(h); 
        }
        int d=f.size();
        for(int i=0;i<f.size();i++) {
            cout<<f[i]<<endl;
    }
```

The entire code of the above code is at https://ideone.com/4NgCWz . Plz help!

Comment: in general you should check if the iterator you get from algorithms equals `passed.end()`, because you are not allowed to derefence the end iterator. And in this case your `index` might be off

Answer (score 0):

At second iteration of cycle in line #57 you get index = 2 for array:

```
$5 = std::vector of length 2, capacity 2 = {"codechef", "google"}
```

You should check that result of "lower_bound()" is not equal passed.end().
If it is equal, than lower_bound() return iterator to end, not to last element.

Comment: Thnx for the information!..this was the first time i used this stl

Comment: But i want to know...what statement will i write to avoid the lower bound() from returning iterator to the end

Comment: @lazarus you cant avoid it, but you can check if it did return end: `if (low == pased.end()) { /* handle this case*/} else { /* use low */}`